# How to filter Product Grid based on custom attribute?

Tags: magento-1.7, module, collection, grid, filter

I have a custom product attribute `soldby` which is a dropdown attribute.

I am making a custom product grid. In that grid, I want to display products where `soldby`=abc.

I have written the following code in Grid.php.

### prepareCollection()

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('soldby');
$collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
    array('attribute'=>'soldby','eq'=>'abc'),
));
```

But this doesnot work. Now, no products are shown even though there are products with attribute `soldby`=abc.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: If it is an attribute, you can use `addAttributeToFilter('soldby', array('eq' => 'abc'))`

Comment: It is not working.
P.S: It is a custom product attribute.  @John

Comment: You can try $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSort("entity_id","DESC")
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('soldby', 'abc');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass option id instead of 'abc', and for this you have to get option id first. Try this, it will resolve your issue :

```
$attributeCode = 'soldby';
$optionText = 'abc';
$attributeId = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product',$attributeCode);
$attr = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);
if ($attr->usesSource()) {
    $attributeOptions = $attr ->getSource()->getAllOptions();
    foreach ($attributeOptions as $option) {
    if($option['label']==$optionText){           
        $optionTextId = $curattributeid=$option['value'];
        break;
    }
      }
    }

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(array(
    array('attribute'=>$attributeCode,'eq'=>$optionTextId),
));
```

Comment: Thank u.. its working :)

Answer (score 1):

Try below code :

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('soldby', array('eq' => 'abc'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addAttributeToFilter('soldby', 'abc');`

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
       parent::__construct();

        $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSort("entity_id","DESC")
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('soldby', 'abc')
            ->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInSiteIds())
            ->setPageSize($this->get_prod_count())
            ->addAttributeToSort($this->get_order(), $this->get_order_dir())
            ->setCurPage($this->get_cur_page());

        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);
        Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($products);

        $this->_productCollection = $products;

        return $this->_productCollection;
    }
```